# ByteBuddy - transform all methods

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I am trying to mimic mock creation with byte buddy.
Is it possible to intercept all methods at once?

I tried the following:

```
new ByteBuddy()
   .subclass(Object.class)
   .method(nameMatches(".*"))
   .intercept(FixedValue.nullValue())
```

but it unfortunately does not work

Comment: How is this an assembly question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible doing this:

```
new ByteBuddy()
  .subclass(Object.class)
  .method(any())
  .intercept(StubMethod.INSTANCE);
```

You cannot use `nullValue()` as some methods do not return anything or a primitive type where `null` cannot be assigned. Therefore, Byte Buddy throws an exception for your example which indicates this.